# Trying to get a button to toggle through questions and submit at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple form that uses jQuery to display one question at a time. My code works fine if I want it to submit only at the very end of the questioning process.

However, I want to have my form submit the answers to the url bar as the questions get answered.

Here is my code:

```
<script language="javascript">
  function displayquestion(a){
    $(".questionholder").stop().hide();
    $("#question"+a).stop().show();
  }
  function exefunction2(){
    document.forms["TheForm"].submit();
  }
</script>

<body onLoad="insertForm()">
<form id="TheForm">
<div class="questionholder" id="question1" style="display:block">
    What is your first name?<br>
    <input name="answer1"><br>
    <input type="button" class="sub" onclick="exefunction2();displayquestion(2);" id="button">
    <a onclick="displayquestion(2)">next</a>
</div>
<div class="questionholder" id="question2" style="display:none">
    What is your last name?<br>
    <input name="answer2"><br>
    <input type="button" class="sub" onclick="exefunction2();displayquestion(3);" id="button">
    <a onclick="displayquestion(3)">next</a>
</div>
</form>

<script language="javascript">
  var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  var answer1 = urlParams.get('answer1');
  var answer2 = urlParams.get('answer2');
  document.write(answer1 + ' ' + answer 2);
</script>
```

I DO NOT have access to a server or to other files in the directory of the PC. Everything must be handled and displayed through the same HTML file. That's just the reality of my environment, I cannot use the internet in any form.

So with the code above, I see question2 extrememly briefly before question 1 pops up and I have an infinite loop where only question 1 can be answered, the entire form gets submitted (all further questions are null or default values), question 2 quickly appears and gets replaced by question 1.

I can't figure out how to get my code to stay at question 2.

Comment: Next time, update your question instead of deleting the old one and repeating it again.

Comment: Do you want it fixed or do you want to know why it's broken? If your curious and want to know why it's broken then we need the rest of the code. TBH, if the code on your post a good indication for the rest of the code then I'd reassess it's wroth because it's jQuery using onevent attribute handlers. That means there's a real code and then there's the one you have modified...

Comment: How much more code do you want? That's all there is. The user completes the form and the final result is spit out again. What I want is for the input to be updated in the url bar as it gets completed, rather than only at the end.

Answer (score 0):

There is not much point in changing the url bar without any actual request being made by it to the server, so any regular action with the form involving the url-bar would generally lead to a request being sent with it as well.

However since you have your goal set I can think of 2 options to go about:

1) post the form with every answer made, and when the page reloads with the new param identify how many params are there and decide according to that which question should be shown to the user. This would result in a very poor user experience though.

2) The second option is to add a simple manipulation of the url-bar url string whenever a an answer is submitted. I will show this method.

The function to use is `window.history.pushState()` which will manipulate the url string for you.

Basically whenever a question is answer you can do this by simply adding some code in the `displayquestion()` function:

```
function displayquestion(a){
  $(".questionholder").stop().hide();
  $("#question"+a).stop().show();
  // Get the needed data:
  let prev = a-1;
  let key = `answer${prev}`;
  let val = $(`input[name='answer${prev}']`).val();
  // Change url with data:
  let url = 'window.location.pathname';
  if(prev===1){
    url = url + `?${key}=${val}`;
  } else {
    url = url + "&${key}=${val}";
  }
  window.history.pushState(key, key, url);
}
```

Comment: Using this doesn't change the result for me at all. It still behaves the same way.